# Documentation examples for non-trivial ES6 code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, ecmascript-2016

I am struggling to find decent documentation samples/references to document ES6 code, like some sort of cheatsheet for ES6 documentation.

I'd like to align on JSDoc documentation, however amongst the most common answers to this question, I can only manage to find **trivial** code documentation, and not documentation that fits new ES6+/React syntaxes or more complex params like Arrays, maps, param deserializations, etc..

For instance [does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions) gives only documentation examples regarding regular JS function with standard params.

I'd like to find rules / nice way to document something like this, how to indicate params that are required or not, etc.

An exemple of method I'd like to document

```
const signInWithCredentials = ({ emails, password, authentication_code }, options) => {

}
```

I can think of something like this

```
**
 * Attempts sign in with any possible credentials pair
 * (Provide either email + password, or an authentication_code and a provider name in the options
 * @param { 
 *   emails: { Array<String> },
 *   password: { String },
 *   authentication_code: { String }
 * } - credentials
 * @param { Object } - options
 * @param { String } - options.provider
```

But I'm not really sure how to handle deserialized params that don't really have a name `function({ param1, param2 })`, are nested `function({ param1: { nestedParam1, nestedParam2 })` or are renamed `function({ param1: name1 })` and how to handle composed types like an array of xxx

I am already using `PropTypes` for several method declarations but they only work when using React components, but are less useful when writing utility functions, etc. outside of react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just realized the JSDoc had an official page with documentation samples and that this included a section regarding destructuration

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

```
Documenting a destructuring parameter
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
    // ...
};
```